# 'No module named kivy' when virtualenv is active?

Tags: python, virtualenv, kivy, python-module

I originally installed Cython and Kivy on mac without a virtualenv, but decided to create a virtualenv in my project after the fact. I uninstalled Cython and Kivy, then reinstalled (without sudo) both with my virtualenv active.

When I run 'pip freeze' it lists kivy, but when I try to run my code it returns the error: 'ImportError: No module named kivy.' When I deactivate my virtualenv the program runs fine.

I think I ran into a similar problem when first learning Django. Could anyone enlighten me on what causes this? I know I'm missing something fundamental about modules and virtualenv.

Also, where would I find the kivy installation, both inside and outside of a virtualenv? Where does pip install it? From my understanding what I'm asking is not unique to kivy.

Thanks in advance for the insight!

just using the first example app kivy gives:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: What command are you using for running and which python version you are using?/

Comment: You can import kivy and print kivy.__file__ to see where it's installed.

Comment: python 2 and just running python main.py from terminal. import kivy was not working. At the moment I am just using global packages but obviously that is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`pip freeze` displays both global and local packages; you've installed Kivy as a global package but inside a virtual environment only local packages are available for Python.

Either install Kivy in the virtual environment (`pip install` after activating venv) or enable access to the global packages (recreate venv with option `--system-site-packages` or use command `toggleglobalsitepackages` from virtualenvwrapper).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really understand how global packages mixed in with virtualenvs. I will vote as best answer when I try in a bit.